# How do I unsubscribe to the dispatch to grab new data onload on useEffect? - I'm using Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I can load my data but only after I refresh the page. Until then, it shows the data from the previous item I clicked on. It's behaving like a cache would.

Here is my mediaSlice

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL
const HBO_SINGLE_MEDIA_API = `${BASE_URL}/titlestest`

const initialState = {
  media:{},
  status: 'idle',  //'idle', 'loading', 'succeeded', 'failed'  
  error:null
}

export const fetchSingleMediaTitle = createAsyncThunk(
  'media/fetchSingleMediaTitle', 
  async (id) => { 
    const response = await axios.get(
      HBO_SINGLE_MEDIA_API,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-API-KEY': KEY,
        },
        params: {
          titleId: id,
        }
      }
    )

    return response.data.Item;
  } 
)

const mediaSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'media',
  initialState,
  reducers:{},
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchSingleMediaTitle.pending]: () => {
      console.log("Pending");
    },
    [fetchSingleMediaTitle.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.status = 'succeeded'
      state.media = payload
    },
    [fetchSingleMediaTitle.rejected]: () => {
      console.log("Rejected");
    },
  }
})

// SELECTORS
export const selectSingleMedia = (state) => state.media.media;

export const getMediaStatus = (state) => state.media.status;

export default mediaSlice.reducer
```

And then the Media Component has what you would expect

```
const [media, setMedia] = useState([]);   
const {id} = useParams();
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const singlemedia = useSelector((state) => selectSingleMedia(state, id))
const mediaStatus = useSelector(getMediaStatus)

useEffect(() => { 
  if (mediaStatus === 'idle') {
    dispatch(fetchSingleMediaTitle(id)) //yes, it's imported
  }
    
  setMedia(singlemedia); 

  //it returns the array with the data but not the current one
  console.log("singlemedia: ", singlemedia); 

  return () => {  };
  // Someone suggested removing the dependencies below but then it doesn't load anything.
}, [id, singlemedia, mediaStatus, dispatch, media_data])
```

I am at a loss here because as I understand it, the useEffect is supposed to fire onload and give me the current data. The ID is correct in the params but the state is not mutating.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
For reference, here is the console log. Those console logs are in the useEffect. The API is slightly slower than the useEffect and the render is happening before the data is ready (race condition) or at least that's what I think it's happening here that's why it loads empty and then it loads again. But the confusing part is that ALL of that happens on a page refresh only. On a normal load the state is not empty is loaded and in time for the UI to render it (no race condition), only, it's loaded with the old data from a previous state shape

[image]

Here is the redux dev tools
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector takes one argument, but you're passing it two. Change it to:

```js
const singlemedia = useSelector(selectSingleMedia);
```

Second, your `singlemedia` is the state. There's no need to `setMedia(singlemedia);`.

Your `useEffect` should look like:

```js
useEffect(() => { 
  if (mediaStatus === 'idle') {
    dispatch(fetchSingleMediaTitle(id));
  }
}, [dispatch, id, mediaStatus]);
```

Also, you should look into RTK Query, which would replace `createAsyncThunk`: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/rtk-query

### Edit per our [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244343/discussion-between-onosendi-and-lotusms):

```js
useEffect(() => { 
  dispatch(fetchSingleMediaTitle(id));
}, [dispatch, id]);
```

Comment: It didn't change anything. I 'll look inot RTK as well

Comment: When you first load the component, is it not updating your state with the fetched data?

Comment: no sir. it loads the old payload

Comment: That doesn’t make any sense. When the component is first mounted, there isn’t an “old payload”. Unless, are you persisting your Redux state with something like Redux Persist?

Comment: I agree it doesn't make any sense. Hence why I'm here. lol It's driving me nuts. I come to this page from a Medias page that renders a collection of movies by clicking on movie "A" and passing the id to it. Then this page is a Media Details page which loads Media "A" by the ID that it received. The very first time I run the application, this runs exactly as expected. The state DOES provide me back with the data for Media "A". Then, I click back to the Medias page and click Media "B" and when the Media Details page opens the Media "A" data is persisting despite the new ID given. Until refresh

Comment: Ok, so when you first load the media page the result is correct, but when you leave the page and come back, the result is the same? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244343/discussion-between-onosendi-and-lotusms).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very simple, just remove the media internal state variable:

```
const [media, setMedia] = useState([]);
```

As what you are doing now is that you send the async request here:

```
if (mediaStatus === 'idle') {
    dispatch(fetchSingleMediaTitle(id)) //yes, it's imported
  }
```

And before the backend responds you read the store and set it in the internal state:

```
setMedia(singlemedia); // This is old data now, as we are waiting for the backend
```

If you wish to display the store state just use singlemedia in the render method.

If you wish to have some temporary state that mimics a backend response again use singlemedia and implement the temporary state in the redux store.

PS. the useEffect should depend only on id and useDispatch

Comment: I'm a little confused. drop the state? to what line? and what's BE?. Unless you meant get rid of the state and just use singlemedia to populate the UI, but it still didn't help

Comment: Also, though I think you are not 100% wrong, I also think the problem is somewehre else because I don't see a rerender on the redux console when I go to a new item, alsmost as if it's ignoring the ID.

Comment: Ok, I see that I did not express myself properly, let me try again:
The internal state is not needed at all, you can remove it.
If the store is updated and you are using useSelector for the singleMedia variable this variable will be updated automatically, thus you can just use it in the render.
BE = back end

Comment: You can use Redux dev tools to see if the state changes as you expect, if that is correct make sure you are selecting the thing that changes in the store.
Oh and one more maybe more problematic error, in the slice you should be sending a new variable (different reference) or the update mechanisms will not work, the idea of Redux is that the reference to the state must be different on every change.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought you meant. Can you put it in your answer? I'm not sure what you mean by sending a new variable. I removed the state and using the payload in singlemedia from the useSelector but it dint change anything. And I checked Redux Dev Tools and nothing updates there either unless I refresh

Comment: I clarified the answer, but it is still weird that the state is not updating.
For the state change RTK actually has you covered, without RTK you would need to pass a new object, but RTK has removed that need, I got confused there.
I checked again the code and the communication with the backend looks good as well as the Redux reducer, it is weird that the store is not updating. Can you check if the thunk actions are visible in the redux dev tools, i.e. do you see the media/fetchSingleMediaTitle events.

Comment: Reference to why you do not need to pass a new variable while using RTK: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers

Comment: I'm updating my question with a couple of screenshots from the console. Stand by. I appreciate you taking your time with this man. I've been fighting this bug for a week and I'm the only dev in house